# Supernovae apparent magnitude in a simplified LCDM model

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, computational-physics, software, supernova

I want to generate some fake apparent magnitude of supernovae Ia at different redshift  using the LCDM model and the fiducial absolute magnitude of supernovae Ia (-19.35) and I want to compare it with the real data.
I am using the following formula with $\Omega_m= 0.3$, $H_0=65 km/s$ and $\Omega_{DE}= 0.7$

$$H(z) = H_0 \sqrt{(\Omega_m*(1+z)^3+ \Omega_{DE})}$$

from which i get the luminosity distance

$$d_l(z)= (1+z)* \int_{0}^z \frac{1}{H_0}\,dz $$

then the modulus distance
$$\mu(z)= 5 \log_{10}(d_l) + 25 $$
and finally the apparent magnitude
$m= \mu - 19.35$

but when I try to plot the results against the real supernovae apparent magnitude (from the pantheon dataset)  the results totally different from the real ones. is it because of the simplifications or there is something wrong in the equations i have used?

[image]

p.s.: I don't know if the error is in the equations above or in the python code I am using though

i will leave it here but if i will remove it if the rules do not allow it

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
number_of_pred = 5000
x_pred = np.linspace(0.001,2.5,number_of_pred)
omegam=0.3
omegade=0.7

def invhubble(z):
   return (1/(65* np.sqrt(omegam*(1+z)**3+ omegade  )))

def luminosity(z):
  res= (1+z)* quad(invhubble,0,z)[0]
  return   res 

def distancemodulus(z):
  return np.log10(luminosity(z))+25 

y_mock_tot = np.array([*map(distancemodulus,x_pred)])-19.35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try with these equations, if it still does not work share your code in your OP. I'll try my best to help

$$M_{B,i} = m_{B,i} - \mu(z_i)$$

where

$$\mu(z_i) = 5\log_{10}\Big[\frac{1+z_i}{10{\rm pc}}\int_0^{z_i}\frac{cdz}{H(z)}\Big]$$

**Be careful about the units!**

I recommend you to chose

1. $[H_0]$:km/s/Mpc
2. $[c]$:km/s

There's also $10$pc which you need to convert to Mpc.

And, as an advice always label your axis and put units if available.

Note:

```
def distancemodulus(z):
  return np.log10(luminosity(z))+25
```

You should also multiply with $5$.

Comment: it works, thankyou!

Comment: your welcome, happy to help